# Unpacking .bundle files via terminal

Tags: mac, terminal

There's a known method for unpacking .bundle by going to [Show Package Contents](http://lifehacker.com/313516/unpacking-mac-os-x-bundles), but what if that option is unavailable?

There is a solution that works for .pkg files by using the [pkgutil --expand](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/26/show-package-contents-unavailable-extract-pkg-files-without-installing-them/) command. Is there any solution for .bundle?

Comment: ls /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Spotlight.prefPane/Contents/

Answer (score 2):

I was under the impression that .bundle files are actually folders - in your terminal application, try typing the following:

```
cd archive_name.bundle
ls
```

---

For example, on my end:

```
cd IMDB.bundle/
ls
$Contents   README.md
```